# What is the ProgressDB equivalent to SQL Server's statement Select ID = '1'?

Tags: sql-server, openedge, progress-db

When attempting to use a query I wrote against a Progress DB, I assumed I could use the following statement:

```
SELECT ID = '1' FROM Table
```

That returns a syntax error, but it's perfectly normal syntax for SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule #1 -- Progress is not SQL.  The more you try to make it act like SQL the unhappier you will be.

There is a SQL-92 interface.  Naturally it does not support much in the way of syntax specific to Microsoft or Oracle.  "Perfectly normal for MS SQL Server" is no assurance that Progress will think it normal.

There is an older still SQL-89 embedded within the 4GL engine.  This is even less likely to behave like MS SQL.

Of course a great deal depends on which of these engines you are using and what version of Progress you are working with.

Having said that -- you have no table name.  I'm just a Progress guy and maybe that's some sort of fancy-pants MS SQL magic or a code snippet from the midst of something more interesting but that looks like a problem to me.  I would have been coding something more like:

```
SELECT name FROM customer WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: I tried it with a known table name and got the same syntax error.  Updated question as well to reflect that.  At this point, I'm assuming there's no Progress equivalent way of doing this and thus the syntax error.  This is a common thing to do when trying to hard code a value as part of the select statement.  Useful when you just want to test connectivity to a DB or table without having to know what the columns/tables are.  Like a health check.

Comment: Like i said, I'm a Progress guy, not a SQL guy but your syntax looks kind of messed up to me.  At least from a standard SQL perspective.  Where is your WHERE?  Why do you want id = 1 to be directly after SELECT?  Is ID a character field?  (You have quoted the '1')  Are you using the 4GL engine or the SQL-92 engine?  What is the text of the error message?

Comment: What does "hard code a value" mean and how is that conceptually different from WHERE ID = 1?

Comment: The difference is there may not be any records on the DB that satisfy `WHERE ID = 1`, in fact there may not even be a column on the table called `ID` at all, in which case in SQL server, you just get back a column called `ID` with a hard coded value of '1' for each row in `Table`, or if you don't specify a table, then you get back one row.  Whereas with Progress, there doesn't appear to be a way to do this, which is ok, I just needed to know this so I could write the test queries differently.

Comment: That sounds  bizarre to me.  So far as I know there is nothing similar from a Progress perspective.  But if you do have a connection all of the metaschema tables should be available to run a test query.

Comment: Ok, that will accomplish what we are trying to do.